# Can not read PHP JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, joomla

I'm trying to read a JSON file created on a PHP file.

This is joomla 2.5

This is my function:

```
$combo="$( document ).ready(function() {    
  $.getJSON( 'components/com_vmvendor/views/addproduct/tmpl/datos.php', function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      alert(key);
    });      
  });      
});";    
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($combo);
```

This only should read file datos.php and send some alerts but it doesn't anything.
This is the PHP JSON file (datos.php):

```
<?php
  $data = array(    
    "status" => 1,
    "firstname" => "foo",
    "lastname" => "bar",    
  );

  header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($data);
```

The curious thing is the function works with JSON pages like below (datos.json).

```
{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

So JSON pages are working but not PHP. What can be happening?

Comment: Please use the preview... please...

Comment: You may have to quote this line ´"status" => 1.´  ´"status" => "1"´

Comment: @T9b that's not needed. JSON will treat it as a number http://i.imgur.com/daZSYdO.png

Comment: this code should work , the problem must be with joomla

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser console network tab. You are clearly not following joomla documented methods to creat a json controller